# "filedescriptor out of range in select()" when using python's subprocess with rsync

Tags: python, subprocess, rsync

the code below is used to sync uploaded picture to another place. it works, but after a period of time(about 10 days), the service is unusable , showing error: 'filedescriptor out of range in select()', but restart service solves the problem.

```
# sync.py

def sync_file(source_pic, hashval, retry_num=3):

    pic_path = os.path.join(gen_dir(hashval), os.path.split(source_pic)[1])
    filename = tempfile.mkstemp()[1]
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(pic_path)

    for sync_path in options.sync_paths:
        try_num = 0
        rsync_cmd = ['rsync','-au', '--files-from='+filename, options.pic_path, sync_path]

        while try_num < retry_num:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(rsync_cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            stdout_value, stderr_value = proc.communicate()

            if len(stderr_value) != 0:
                logger.error('sync failed: %s' % stderr_value)
                try_num = try_num + 1
                #raise UploadException('sync failed')
            else:
                break

    os.remove(filename)
```

log info:

```
File "/path/to/sync.py", line 25, in sync_file
    stdout_value, stderr_value = proc.communicate()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 691, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1211, in _communicate
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(read_set, write_set, [])
    ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

are there unclosed file descriptors that cause the error? it seems subprocess doesn't close file descriptor, so when it runs 1024 times, the file descriptor is out of range. (we are using python 2.6, subprocess is forced to use select.select() which has a limit of 1024 file descriptors even epoll is available)

Comment: finally i remove the PIPE redirect when Popen, and checking `proc.returnval`, it seems working.

Answer (score 3):

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=609020

> Prior to Python 2.7, programs that used `ulimit -n` to enable
>   communication with large numbers of subprocesses could still monitor
>   only 1024 file descriptors at a time, which caused an exception:
>
> ```
> ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
> ```
>
> This was due to the subprocess module using the `select` system call. 
>   The module now uses the `poll` system call, removing this limitation.

possible fix: use python 2.7+, or backport the code using `poll`.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually close the file descriptors. After calling `communicate`, call `proc.stderr.close()` and `proc.stdout.close()`.

Comment: Does this actually solve the issue? I looked at the sources of `subprocess`, and it looks like the descriptors should be closed automatically in `_communicate`.

Comment: I agree, they *should* be. But for some reason in your case they're not.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no luck :( after some day running , still have the same error

Comment: Then my bet is some other code is leaking file descriptors eventually causing this code to fail. It may help to use a tool that lists the open files a process has. Give the code a few hours, then run the tool.

Comment: I'm stuck at the same problem - did you figure this out, @limboy?